Can Vedic Suktam be chanted mentally?
The Stotras of the deities are a part of the vocal worship. Does it produce any fruits when chanted mentally? What about the Vedic Suktams? Can these be chanted mentally? Or do these Suktams have to be chanted aloud?

Internal chanting abides by Bhavana. Yoga has a good reference to Bhava. So the answer is yes. Bhavana-Matra-Santustayai Namaha :- She who just by Bhavana will become happy.
